# Having problems with an xsl:choose tag

Tags: xslt

I have an xsl question, I'm trying to use an xsl:choose.  Below is the snippet.  The problem is that the `<xsl:otherwise>` tag always fires, which makes me believe that the `<xsl:when>` isn't evaluating properly.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']='Full'">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ff00ff">
      <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']"/>
    </td>   
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']"/></td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `[1]` to the `<xsl:when>` test like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel'][1]='Full'">
    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ff00ff">
      <xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']"/>
    </td>   
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']"/></td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Otherwise, the `./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']` selector will return (essentially) a list of matching elements (hopefully just one in your case. You need `[1]` to select the first matching `Property` element.

---

Also, I'm assuming your source element looks something like:

```
<node>
  <Property Name="RecoveryModel">Full</Property>
<node>
```

Comment: It doesn't like  the .text() Expected token 'eof' found '.'. ./Property[@Name ='RecoveryModel']-->.<--text()='Full'

Comment: Awesome. If it's solved the problem for you you can click the hollow tick next to my answer to accept it so that others know that this solves the problem.

Comment: The /text() is unnecessary, and not recommended.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks, I had suspected that was the case. Answer amended.